# delete button delete record from the database but not from the frontend

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

When pressing the delete button it successfully delete the record from database. But not delete from the frontend it gives result after reloading or refreshing the page.

My view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<a href="#" class="phone_number" onclick="del(this)" data-id="@item.id">
 <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
</a> 
}
<script>
 function del(x) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("deleteRent", "Home")';
            
            var rd = x.dataset.id
            debugger

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: rd
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.length == 0) // No errors
                        alert("Delete success!");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) { // Http Status is not 200
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, status) { // Whether success or error it enters here
                }
            });
        };
       </script>
```

Comment: Do you mean when you delete this data in db, But it still show in the page and you don't wanna it show?

Comment: yes i do not want to show after pressing delete button

Comment: Without knowing *what* you are deleting (on the UI), it's hard to give any specific help.  You have three options: reload the entire page, load a page fragment, or remove the related HTML.  eg if the `<a>` is on a `tr` then you could do `$(x).closest("tr").remove()`  (might be a good idea to give it a better variable name than 'x')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you delete from database but you don't refresh your page.

Either, you use answer from Dipendrasinh Vaghela and you refresh the whole page.

Or if you have a function which search and show in DOM, you call it when delete is success. That'll update "only" the part showing datas.

Answer (score 0):

Please add window.location.reload() code after alert....

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.length == 0) // No errors
                    alert("Delete success!");
                    **window.location.reload();**
            },
```

this code automatically reload your page after success

Comment: You want to it without refresh? @Qasim Asghar

Comment: is there not any other way without reloading the page

Comment: other way is you can reload a particular part like div, table ,etc. which you want

Comment: how to reload particular part i make it in a div then how to reload that div only

Comment: Please review third sentence answer of pier farrugia